# Upload a file from local pc to GCP bucket using CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I wanted to know if there was a way to upload files from your local device to a project's home directory or to a bucket directly from the gcloud CLI in your browser.

The documentation from google only covers uploading from the console and moving from home directory to a bucket using CLI

Answer (score 3):

Do you think it might be possible to use `gsutil cp` CLI command? Some documentation is here: [cp - Copy files and objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

You might need to install GCP SDK locally on your machine - [Google Cloud Command Line Interface (gcloud CLI)](https://cloud.google.com/cli) and [Install the gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) - as a prerequisite.

In addition, there might be no such thing as "a project's home directory" in the GCP world (ontology) (unless I misunderstood that part of your question), so this particular thing might not be possible at all. A GCS bucket should be a perfect destination however.